# filter hyperlinks - python

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want to get all the hyperlinks from a website whose URL text includes words like `product` `service` `solution` `index`

So I came up with this

```
site = 'https://www.similarweb.com'
resp = requests.get(site)
encoding = resp.encoding if 'charset' in resp.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, from_encoding=encoding)

contact_links = []
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if 'product' in a['href'] or 'service' in a['href'] or 'solution' in a['href'] or 'about' in a['href'] or 'index' in a['href']:
        contact_links.append(a['href'])

contact_links2 = []
for i in contact_links:
    string2 = i
    if string2[:4] == 'http':
        contact_links2.append(i)
    else:
        contact_links2.append(site+i)

for i in contact_links2:
    print i
```

When running this snippet on https://www.similarweb.com it gives several links some of which are

```
https://www.similarweb.com/apps/top/google/app-index/us/all/top-free
https://www.similarweb.com/corp/solution/travel/
https://www.similarweb.com/corp/about/
http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2016/10/17/drudge-limbaugh-fall-for-twitter-joke-about-postal-worker-destroying-trump-ballots.html
https://www.similarweb.com/apps/top/google/app-index/us/all/top-free
```

Following this result, I want only those links where after these words `product` `service` `solution` `index` there should not be any more words

expected output:
(considering only previous 5 links)

```
https://www.similarweb.com/corp/about/
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Which of the sample URLs do you want to be removed?

Comment: the ones, where `product` `service` `solution` `index` should be last word in URL

Comment: @LutzHorn which follows I want only third URL amongst sample ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have backslashes before and after the words you are checking in if condition. It should be `if '/product/' in a['href'] ...` and so on.

As mentioned in the comments that it should be the last word then better check `a['href'].endswith('/product/')`.
As endswith function can take tuple as parameter so you can do this way

`if a['href'].endswith(('/product/', '/index/', '/about/', '/solution/', 'service'))`.

This condition will evaluate to true for all urls that ends with any of the strings mentioned in the tuple.

Comment: can we also include regular expression here so that variants can be covered. like `about` `aboutus` `about-us` along with endswith

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin


r = requests.get('https://www.similarweb.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
urls = set()

for i in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'((about)|(product)|(service)|(solution)|(index))/$')):
    url = i.get('href')
    abs_url = urljoin(r.url, url)
    urls.add(abs_url)
print(urls)
```